# JSF2 f:ajax ajax requests without query string?

Tags: ajax, post, jsf-2, richfaces, prettyfaces

Right now on each f:ajax (or a4j:ajax) request I'm making, the POST includes the query string which I don't want.  Is there a way to not have it pass them on?  I don't understand why it does this anyways.

Example:  Request page

GET /mypage.xhtml?zipcode=10101

Then any ajax calls fired by f:ajax on that page does a post like so:

POST /mypage.xhtml?zipcode=10101

This causes a lot of problems because if i changed the form element for zip on the page with ajax, any other ajax post will actually cause the original zip code passed into the page to get re-read and reset on my backing bean.

I really want to tell all f:ajax calls to STOP putting the request parameters in the URL, like so:

POST /mypage.xhtml (regardless of what request paremteres were on the original page GET).

Comment: Just a note, I noticed that a4j on JSF1 does NOT do this, it would submit POST's without the querysting that came into the original page.

Comment: It looks like the action that h:form's render includes the query string, like this:

`<form id="myForm-j_idt47" name="myForm-j_idt47" method="post" action="/mypage.xhtml?zipcode=10101" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">`

I guess I need to see if there is a way to modify h:form's action

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you have view params defined.

Comment: I don't have any view params defined.

Comment: I noticed any default values i set on my backing bean that the form is meant to populate get added to the form action as well... maybe these are all being set as view params somehow that isn't explicitly by me.  I am also using prettyfaces, maybe it is doing something.